# How can I change specific text in an HTML page, except for when it appears in an HTML attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I want to change all occurrences of a specific string in the body of an HTML page with the following Javascript code:

```
body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML.replaceAll('selectedText', `<span>Changed Text</span>`);
```

It was Ok until I faced the following html in Google Docs:

```
<div class="navigation-item" aria-label="PST" aria-disabled="false">
  <div data-tooltip="PST">PST</div>
</div>
```

In this situation I don't want to replace PST in the `aria-label` and `data-tooltip`. I just want to replace PST in the `div` tag with `<span>Changed Text<span>`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can replace '>selectedText' with '>newtext'

Comment: @Emanuele Thanks You can share it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace '>selectedText' with '>newtext'

Comment: I checked this answer it can not be a correct answer when we have <div data-tooltip="PST">1:20 PST</div>

Answer (score 0):

If you have the luxury of using jQuery you may try:

```
jQuery('div:contains(pattern)').each(function(i){this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace('pattern', 'newpattern')})
```